# wcf rest and android post method

Tags: android, rest, post, methods, service

I have written a wcf rest using vs template my post in c# rest look like this

```
[LWebInvoke(UriTemplate ="",Method="POST")]
public DMSDateTime Create( DMSDateTime instance)
{
return instance;

 }
```

The DMSDateTime is below

```
public class DMSDateTime()
{
 public DMSDateTime(){
 Date =System. DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Time=System. DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
 }

 public string Date{get; set;}
 public string Time{get; set;}

 }
 }
```

Android part is below

```
 String s ="<DMSDateTime>\r\n<Date>20-01-2014</Date>\r\n<Time>06:00:00</Time>\r\n</DMSDateTime>";
 HttpClient httpclient =new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost request = new     HttpPost("http://test.com:4567/disservice/");
 StringEntity sa = new StringEntity(s);
 sa.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
 sa.setContentType("text/XML");
 request.setEntity(sa);
 httpclient.execute(request);
```

I am getting bad request as response status code 400 kindly help... Please excuse me indent is not correct my company dont allow to post code so I saw the code and typed in my cellphone...

If I make get request it works fine

Answer (score 0):

write your webservice like this :-

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
          UriTemplate = "Login?parameter={parameter}")]
          string Login(string parameter);


     public string Login(string parameter)
        {



            /*
             * input :=  {"username":"kevin","password":"123demo"}
             * output:=  1=sucess,0=fail
             *
            */

            //Getting Parameters from Json  
            JObject jo = JObject.Parse(parameter);
            string username = (string)jo["username"];
            string password = (string)jo["password"];
            return ""+username;
    }
```

and Access this service in Android like this :-

```
public static String getJsonData(String webServiceName,String parameter)
{  
    try  
    {
    String urlFinal=SERVICE_URI+"/"+webServiceName+"?parameter=";
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(urlFinal.trim()+""+URLEncoder.encode(parameter,"UTF-8"));
    postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
    Log.i("response", ""+response.toString());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    final String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    string=responseText;
    Log.i("Output", ""+responseText);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {

    }

return string;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use XML only no json